# How to concatenate a string in two different line after nl2br function

Tags: javascript, php

I'm having difficulties to create a JavaScript variable using the `n12br()` function in php. Below is example code:

```
var example = "<?php echo nl2br("line 1 \n line 2") ?>";
```

this produces the following output:

```
var example = "line 1<br>
    line2"
```

Which results in an error due to the line break. How can I concatenate the output to be on one line?

Comment: `nl2br` is a misleading name, because it does not change newlines _into_ a BR element, but it _adds_ a BR to them. So either write your own simple function that replaces newlines with _just_ a BR, or replace the newline characters with “nothing” after using nl2br.

Comment: This works in the above example, but sometimes, if we retrive the data from database, which is already have a new line break without having the '\n' character

Comment: How does something “already have a new line break” without having a newline character in it?

Answer (score 0):

Add a semicolon at the end of the output JS?

Comment: Semicolons in JavaScript aren't strictly necessary.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. I guess I never noticed since it didn't generate an error.

Comment: It's okay, I only found this a few months ago!

Comment: Also, the OP does show a semi-colon in the original example.. Just hasn't copied it into the output (but it would be there in the actual code).

Answer (score 0):

```
var example = '<?php echo str_replace("\n","\u000a", nl2br("line 1 \n line 2")); ?>';
```

Answer (score 0):

### What

As you can see from your output (also CBroe's explanation in the comments and the [PHP manual](http://php.net/nl2br/)) the function `nl2br` inserts a new line tag (`<br>` or `<br />`) before the new line character(s) (`\n`, `\r`, `\n\r`, `\r\n`).

### Why

Multi-line strings are not permitted in JS and will cause a syntax error because as far as the JS engine is concerned the string hasn't been terminated.

### How

...to fix...

Luckily it's easy to create your own function to work aroud this:

```
function jsbrml($string){
    return preg_replace('/(\r\n|\n\r|[\r\n])/', "<br />\\\n", $string);
}

function jsbrsl($string){
    return preg_replace('/(\r\n|\n\r|[\r\n])/', "<br />", $string);
}
```

The first function `jsbrml` will do the same as the default PHP `nl2br` except that it will **insert** `<br />\` instead of just `<br />` the additional back slash at the end of the line allows you to have a multi-line string literal in JS.

The second function `jsbrsl` will remove the line-break characters `\r` and/or `\n` and **replace** with `<br />`.

#### Example `jsbrml`

```
var example = "<?php echo jsbrml("line 1 \n line 2") ?>";

var example = "line1 <br />\
line2";
```

#### Example `jsbrsl`

```
var example = "<?php echo jsbrsl("line 1 \n line 2") ?>";

var example = "line1 <br /> line2";
```